# I would like my python to write my output to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

The output I have appears a columns with quotes. I cant get it to properly write to a csv file.

**This is my output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7wbO.jpg

**This is the code for the output:**

```
import subprocess
import csv

pl = subprocess.Popen(["snmptable", "-v2c", "-c", "public", "104.236.166.95",  "hrSWRunTable"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(pl.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Please consider adding a minimal and reproducible example that will help us to answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Please don't post links to images of text. Copy a sample of the output into your question, instead.

Comment: How about something like `snmptable -v2c -c public -Cb -Cf "," 104.236.166.95 hrSWRunTable > output.csv`? Doesn't even need Python.

Comment: snmptable -v2c -c public -Cb -Cf "," 104.236.166.95 hrSWRunTable > output.csv works but each line is written in a single cell

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do as follows:

```
import csv

with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    employee_writer.writerow(['John Smith', 'Accounting', 'November'])
    employee_writer.writerow(['Erica Meyers', 'IT', 'March'])
```

This will output a `employee_file.csv` which contains

```
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```